# What is the Drupal 7 bookmarking module (a la delicious.com) that is equivalent to userlink in Drupal 6?

Tags: 7, uri, navigation

I am using the [Web Links](http://drupal.org/project/weblinks) in Drupal 6, and I would like to use its equivalent in Drupal 7. It doesn't appear to be a clear direction, according to [Comparison of Links Page modules](http://drupal.org/node/298397).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Drupal 7, I am using the [Link](http://drupal.org/project/link) module. It defines simple link field types.